# jQuery animation longer than duration

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm using jQuery to animate an element when another element is clicked, but there seems to be a short pause before the animation starts, and the console log timer shows that there's an extra 10ms in the animation. Any ideas of what's going on?

```
console.time('animate');
$('.ctr .rightArticle').animate({right: '+='+articleWidth},                 {
    duration: 200,
    easing: 'swing',
    queue: false,
    complete: function() {
        console.timeEnd('animate');
    }
});
```

console shows: animate: 211.985107421875ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The small but noticeable pause was resolved by changed the on('click', function(){}) to on('mousedown', function(){})

It turned out that the 10ms was a red herring.